# How would I change the date when pressing a button?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

Im using NSDate and I got the date to show and it changes it using the iphones time. Im now having trouble changing the date wether its earlier or next day when pressing a button. I need it to be like in the fitness apps where they have the two arrows and you can press on the left one to go to a previous date and the right arrow to go to the next day. How would I do this? Heres the code I have for now:

```
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    dateLabel.zPosition = 22
    dateLabel.fontName = "Krungthep"
    dateLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    dateLabel.fontSize = 17
    dateLabel.text = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle)
    dateLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.0, self.size.height / 1.1)
    self.addChild(dateLabel)

   }

       override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    var touch: UITouch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

            if node.name == "next" {
             //next day

              }







    if node.name == "before" {

        //previous day 
        let earlyDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay,value: -1,toDate:
            NSDate(),options: NSCalendarOptions.WrapComponents)
        date.earlierDate(earlyDate!)


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `NSCalendar`. Specifically, do a search in the Xcode docs on "Calendrical calculations".

You will want to get the current calendar, then create an `NSDateComponents` object, set it's day value to 1 or -1, and then use the method `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options` to add or subtract a day from your date.

Comment: Can you take a look at my updated code when I press the button to go to a previous date it doesn't change.

Comment: How would the code that you've posted make ANY change to the date you're displaying? (Answer, it can't.) You are creating a new date, then calling date.earlierDate and ignoring the results. Your code essentially does nothing.

Comment: So im guessing I have to make changes to the label of the date??

Comment: If you have a label that contains a date, and you want to show a different date, doesn't it stand to reason that you would need to make changes to that label?

Comment: Yes im going to use stringFromDate.